# Strange behavior of "overflow: auto" on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow

I'm developing a site with a blog section. I need this section to have a fixed height. In order to be able to see all the posts in the blog I added an **overflow: auto** so it shows a scrollbar when needed.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
         This is a long post....
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        This is a long post....
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        This is a long post....
    </div>
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
</div>
</div>

#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.post {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I tested this on Chrome, Firefox and IE. The site on Firefox and IE works as expected, but Chrome, although it shows a scrollbar when the list of posts is bigger than the container, adds a white gap the size of the list of posts under the container.

I created a fiddle but I can't reproduce the Chrome behavior there:

http://jsfiddle.net/u5d56/3/

Using **overflow: scroll** instead of auto gives me the same results.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can't reproduce it in a jsFiddle, then you probably have more code that's causing the issue. Also, what's the point of positing a fiddle that doesn't reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. For some reason, for this to work in Chrome I had to add a **position:relative** rule to **#content**:

```
#content{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:visible;
    border 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you! My issue was that the (horizontal) scrollbar seemed to sit under the next element and thus was not *grabable*. `position: relative` on the container fixed the issue.

Comment: ditto, same thing, scroll bar visible but only grabbable at one particular point. Was having trouble with code blocks in a <pre>.

Comment: Ran into something like this -- only on Chrome, and *only on a retina display*! I could actually drag my window to an attached 1x monitor, and watch the page repaint properly, but on the retina side, it would intermittently fail to paint most of the scrolling section. Seems like a straight-up bug, rather than a standards interpretation issue. In any case, your solution was a lifesaver.

Comment: I'd say your answer works not because of the `position:relative` but because of the `overflow:visible` which makes it never show a scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

A possible answer from HTML5 Application Development Fundamentals

```
#content{
     height: 200px;
     region-overflow:auto;
     overflow:visible;
     border 1px solid red;
}
```

Now this is gearing more towards responsive design. Add -webkit- before overflow might help since it is a chrome issue only. Assuming it is CSS3.

```
#content {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```