# Table no longer appending properly with overflow:auto and floated container below

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, overflow

Basically I have a container that holds a table which uses javascript to append data into the table at a regular interval. With this, the container has a style properly `overflow:auto` to allow for it to accommodate a larger amount of data without it looking ugly.

This worked fine, until I placed another container below it with the property `float:left;`. Now the table only displays the first appended item. If I inspect the element, I can 'see' the other appended data items in the code, and a few more appear on the page but nothing like the full table.

If I remove the `overflow:auto` property from the div containing the table, it works (the data will print down the page going 'outside' the container). If I remove the `float:left;` property from the container below it also works. What is preventing them working together?

**UPDATE**: *Instead of using `float:left` on the lower container I added a clearing div so that it would slot in underneath without needing to use float. The issue still remains though, so it seems there is a problem with the container being positioned underneath in general.*

Code is below. 'data' is the container with the table, 'download' is the container lying below. If it matters, the javascript is added below.

```
<div id="data">
    <table id="data_table">
    </table>
</div>
<div id="download"></div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
#data {
    float: left;
    width: 192px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}

#data_table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#data_table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
}

#download {
    width:900px;
    float:left;
    height: 75px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Javascript: (if somehow related)

```
$('#data_table').append('<tr><td><?php echo $catVarValue;?></td><td><?php echo $measVarValue;?></td></tr>');
```

}, );

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem. After trying it in firefox I realised it was a cross-browser issue (as it worked). This led me to:

[Strange behavior of "overflow: auto" on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898335/strange-behavior-of-overflow-auto-on-chrome)

which provides a solution.