# Second level menus don't show in Chrome

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

any idea why a sub-menu appears in Firefox, but not in Chrome when 'overflow' is set as 'auto'? When a scrollbar appear in the menu, the submenus don't become visible (in Chrome).

```
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;

  visibility: hidden;

  font-size: 12px;
  list-style-type: none;

  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 9999;
```

Thanks

Comment: create a complete working snippet here so that it easy for us to resolve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the comment above, but in meantime, two things that may be doing this:
 - Are you sure that the visibility:hidden property and the overflow:auto property are applied to the correct elements? It could be that your visibility code is falling over to the submenu.

Another possible fix is the use of 'position' --> does the element need to be 'fixed' in your case? Changing it to relative helped this poster: [Strange behavior of "overflow: auto" on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898335/strange-behavior-of-overflow-auto-on-chrome)